# Keep on Authorizing the user Twitter4j Android

Tags: android, twitter4j

I can successfully log in to Twitter and can get the details of the user. My TwitterLoginActivity is the class where I put the codes of logging in to twitter. Below is the code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.twitter_login_layout);



        Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);

            try {

                AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
                Log.e("Twitter OAuth Token", "> " + accessToken.getToken());
Intent i = new Intent(TwitterLoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class); 
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                finish();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        loginToTwitter();
    }

private void loginToTwitter() {
        ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
        builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        Configuration configuration = builder.build();

        TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
        twitter = factory.getInstance();

        try {
            requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
            this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
            Log.e("twitterlogin", "logintotwitter-try");
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

And when I press the home button, and go to the app again, it opens a window and ask the user to authorize the app again.

This is weird because what I expect the app would do is that it will show the last view before I press the home button. Could you tell me what to do or what I am doing wrong with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to store that Token information in something like a Shared Preference and save it, when they log in the first time. Then in your onCreate, test whether the user has logged in or not before. If so use the shared preference data.

This tutorial heelped me. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the full android Twitter tutorial](http://hintdesk.com/how-to-tweet-in-twitter-within-android-client/), you can go through steps.